# GITBash terminal error while using csvkit (python)

Tags: git-bash, csvkit

I want to use csvkit from GitBash, windows10,  I am following a DataCamp tutorial and this one:https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/1_getting_started.html#installing-csvkit

After installing csvkit using Jupyter QT (Anaconda) I checked that it was installed using {pip list} .
After that I added the path to csvkit folder in the Environmental variables (Admin).

However I get the error message:
"bash: in2csv: command not found"

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved by reinstalling anaconda, ticking the option to add the path.